multi level navigation in Liferay
I'm currently using Liferay 7.3 to develop a multi-level navigation menu. My navigation structure includes a mega menu and a dropdown menu. However, I'm encountering an issue where the dropdown menu is automatically taking up 100% of the width when it is displayed. This behavior is unintended, as I want the mega menu to take up 100% width while the dropdown menu should only take up its normal width, which is usually narrower and aligns with the content under each navigation item.
To provide more context, I have a navigation menu with multiple levels of hierarchy. The top-level menu items should trigger a mega menu that spans the full width of the container or screen, allowing for multiple columns of links and content. On the other hand, sub-level items (such as those in the dropdown) should only take up as much space as needed, without stretching to the full width.
Currently, both the mega menu and the dropdown are taking up the full 100% width, which causes the dropdown to look too wide and misaligned, especially when there's minimal content in the dropdown. This affects the overall user experience and visual appeal of the site, particularly on larger screens where the dropdown appears unnecessarily stretched.
What I need is a way to adjust the navigation structure so that the mega menu can remain at 100% width when displayed, but the dropdown menu should revert to its normal width, depending on the content. This likely involves making adjustments to the CSS or modifying the FreeMarker template (nav.ftl) used to render the navigation.
To solve this issue, I’m looking for guidance on how to modify the template or CSS to ensure that:
Mega Menu: Continues to display at 100% width when triggered.
Dropdown Menu: Displays at its natural width based on the content, without stretching to 100%.
Here's the current nav.ftl file that I'm working with:
    <!-- Logo -->
    <span class="header-logo hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <a class="${logo_css_class} navbar-brand " href="${site_default_url}"
           title="<@liferay.language_format arguments="${site_name}" key="go-to-x" />">
            <img alt="${logo_description}" src="${site_logo}"
                 class="animate__animated animate__flipInX animate__slower-3s"
                 style="height: 70px; padding: 5px;"/>
            <!-- اسم الموقع حسب اللغة -->
            <#if show_name >
                <span class="site-name ml-2">
                    <#if themeDisplay.getLanguageId()?starts_with("ar")>
                        <!-- طباعة الاسم بالعربية -->
                        ${themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName("ar_SA")}
                    <#else>
                        <!-- طباعة الاسم بالإنجليزية -->
                        ${themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName("en_US")}
                    </#if>
                </span>
            </#if>
        </a>
    </span>

    <!-- Navigation Toggler -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navigation List -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li>
                <span class="header-logo hidden-xs">
                    <a class="${logo_css_class} navbar-brand " href="${site_default_url}"
                       title="<@liferay.language_format arguments="${site_name}" key="go-to-x" />">
                        <img alt="${logo_description}" src="${site_logo}"
                             class="animate__animated animate__flipInX animate__slower-3s"
                             style="height: 63px; padding: 5px;"/>
                        <!-- اسم الموقع حسب اللغة -->
                    <#if show_name >
                        <span class="site-name ml-2">
                            <#if themeDisplay.getLanguageId()?starts_with("ar")>
                                <!-- طباعة الاسم بالعربية -->
                                ${themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName("ar_SA")}
                            <#else>
                                <!-- طباعة الاسم بالإنجليزية -->
                                ${themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName("en_US")}
                            </#if>
                        </span>
                    </#if>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </li>

            <!-- Start of Navigation Items -->
            <#list nav_items as nav_item>
                <#assign nav_item_attr_has_popup = "" />
                <#assign nav_item_css_class = "" />
                <#assign nav_item_layout = nav_item.getLayout() />

                <#if nav_item.isSelected()>
                    <#assign nav_item_attr_has_popup = "aria-haspopup='true'" />
                    <#assign nav_item_css_class = "selected" />
                </#if>

                <!-- Single Menu Item -->
                <#if !nav_item.hasChildren()>
                    <li class="${nav_item_css_class} nav-item" id="layout_${nav_item.getLayoutId()}" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link " ${nav_item_attr_has_popup} href="${nav_item.getURL()} " target="_blank">
                            ${nav_item.getName()}
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Menu Item with Dropdown -->
                <#else>
                    <li class="${nav_item_css_class} nav-item dropdown custom-dropdown" id="layout_${nav_item.getLayoutId()}" role="presentation">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                           aria-expanded="false" ${nav_item_attr_has_popup} href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
                            ${nav_item.getName()}
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>

                        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
                        <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 mt-0 dropdown-menu-custom">
                            <div class="row mx-0">
                                <#list nav_item.getChildren() as nav_child>
                                    <!-- Mega Menu Column -->
                                    <#if nav_child.hasChildren()>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                <p class="mb-0 list-group-item p-1">
                                                    ${nav_child.getName()}
                                                </p>
                                                <#list nav_child.getChildren() as sub_nav_child>
                                                    <a href="${sub_nav_child.getURL()}" target="_blank"
                                                       class="list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1 border-0">${sub_nav_child.getName()}</a>
                                                </#list>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Single Dropdown Item -->
                                    <#else>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="${nav_child.getURL()}"
                                           target="_blank">${nav_child.getName()}</a>
                                    </#if>
                                </#list>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

and this my css file :
    .header-logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #777 !important;
}
.custom-dropdown {
  position: static;
}
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu-custom {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
.mega-menu-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu-custom {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #777;;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar-nav .mega-menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu-custom {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu-custom {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-nav .mega-menu-content .col-lg-3 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  min-width: 25%;
}

.navbar-nav .mega-menu-content .list-group-item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container, .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav .mega-menu-content .col-lg-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.navbar-nav .mega-menu-content .list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #1d3e6c;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle::after {
  content: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu-custom {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }

  .navbar-nav .mega-menu-content {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }



We cannot try this lot of code, pls share some images

I fixed it, thanks
